# how to take screen shot in Qt of a specfic window with a push button?

Tags: qt

I want to add a push button to my qt output application so that when I click the push button it takes the screen shot of my window which is showing the output.
Can someone please tell me the code and the way how can I do that ?

Comment: There is the example of qt screen shot but that is for the complete desktop and I want to take a specfic screen shot for one window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the static grabWindow method on QPixmap with the id of the widget you wish to grab the screenshot from:

```
QPixmap screen_shot = QPixmap::grabWindow(widget->winId())
```

This is valid up until QT 4.8.

In QT 5.0 and above use grab() on the widget itself as below:

```
QPixmap screen_shot = widget->grab();
```

Link:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab